# Hide programmatically a spreadsheet

Tags: java, javascript, google-docs-api, google-apps-script

My question is fairly simple : is it possible to programmatically hide a worksheet in google docs ?

I've searched in the google app script and the java api and I didn't found it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with Google Apps Scripts. There is an [enhancement request in the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=995) if you would care to star it to vote and be notified of status.